# stack information in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

I have got BT for stack as below

```
#0  0x3683e85a in ?? ()
#1  0x2aaea95c in siglongjmp ()

Cannot access memory at address 0xfc29f2eb
```

is it possible to get function or thread name for above bt.
I tried thread commands and info symbol command in GDB but was not successful.

Comment: Sounds like your stack is corrupted. Playing a bit too hard with memory, maybe ?

Comment: yes it is very hard to get it, i tried to get information but was not successful